# Reading input in a predefined order

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I want to read input from a text file in the following order
Read in a url into a String variable, Read in all words after that url into an ArrayList variable. The next time I encounter a url, I want to call a method to perform operations on what I read in so far, before setting the new url into the original String variable and so on.

What I have done so far is

```
public void read() throws IOException {
        PerformCheck pc = new PerformCheck();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        sc.useDelimiter(",");
        String url ="";
        String res ="";
        ArrayList tmp = new ArrayList();
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String s = sc.next().trim();
            if (s.contains("http")){
                url = s;
            }
            else {
                tmp.add(s);

                if (sc.next().contains("http")){ //getting error here
                   result= pc.perform(url,tmp);
                   url= "";
                   tmp= null;
                }

            }

        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

The comment in the code - is where I think I am getting error. Basically, I am trying to look ahead to see if the next token is a url, how can I do this right?

my input file looks like this

> url, word1,word2,word3 url2, word1,word2,word3

Comment: Getting *what* error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save the first time the url and at the second url you check without a lock:
Looks like that:

```
public void read() throws IOException {
        PerformCheck pc = new PerformCheck();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        sc.useDelimiter(",");
        String url = "";
        String res = "";
        boolean lock = true;
        ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String s = sc.next().trim();
            boolean isHttp=s.contains("http");
            if (isHttp && lock) {
                url = s;
                lock=false;
            } 
            else if (isHttp){
                   result= pc.perform(url,tmp);
                   url= s;
                   tmp= new ArrayList<String>();
                // Perform check here
                // url=s
                //tmp=new ArrayList<String>();
            }else {
                tmp.add(s);
            }

        }
        if (tmp.size()>0){
           result=pc.perform(url,tmp);
        }

        sc.close();
    }
```

The lock is only for the first time where you find a url.

Comment: s.contains("http") costs performance, so you should perform it only once.

Comment: how do you account for the fact that at the end of file there is no http, but you still need to run the pc.perform for the last line?

Comment: At the end the while loop is done, but your url and the ArrayList is still full. So you can check it after the while loop

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: not yet, the arraylist apparently isn't reading anything..throwing an error now..

Comment: Sorry I have forgotten the ()

Comment: The else block doesn't seem to be hit at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87643/discussion-between-roy-and-leonid-glanz).

Comment: Could you please upload a piece of the data file?

Comment: it's already specified, just remove the second line (or from url2 onwards)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no "looking ahead" in a scanner. Once you use `next()` it actually attempts to read the next item. And if it hit the end of the file by then, then there won't be a next item, and you'll get an error.

That's why one must always check `hasNext()`, and **always perform just one `next()` per `hasNext()`** (no matter if it's `next()`, `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()` or whatever).

The usual way to deal with such requirements is keep whatever you have read so far, and look at the *current* item that you have read. If it's a URL, you know you should use whatever you collected so far. In pseudo-code:

```
put null in url
put null in list
open the scanner

while there is a next item in the scanner
    set temp to the next item
    if temp is a URL
        if url has a value
            process url and list
        end if
        put temp in url
        create an empty list
    else
        add temp to list
    end if
end while
process the url and list
```

The part that says "if url has a value" means that this is not the first URL that we are reading. That is, `url != null`.

So when you encounter a URL, there are things you do only if there is a previous URL (process the previous data), and there are things you always do (assign the new URL, prepare a new list. If you don't prepare a new list you'll also get an error!).

And if you don't encounter a URL, you know that you already have a prepared list, and you add the item to it.

This way, there is no looking ahead - only looking back.

But it means that after the loop you have a URL and a list that were not processed yet, so that's why you need to perform the "process" operation again.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void read() throws IOException {
    PerformCheck pc = new PerformCheck();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    sc.useDelimiter(",");
    String url ="";
    String res ="";
    boolean firstURLFound = false;
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String s = sc.next().trim();
        if (firstURLFound && s.contains("http")){
            result= pc.perform(url,tmp);
            url= "";
            tmp= new ArrayList<String>();
            firstURLFound = false;
         }
        if (s.contains("http")){
            firstURLFound =true;
            url = s;
        }
        else {
            tmp.add(s);
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```